# Failed to load template in angular $mdDailog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material, mddialog, angularjs-compile

I am using $mdDailog in my angularjs application.I have addUser() function which is called on ng-click operation. Inside addUser() am using $mdDailog.show(). Where I am passing html file path in templateUrl to load.

I am getting error as **Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: editUser.html**

**Controller Function:**

```
function addUser(ev) {
           $mdDialog.show({
           controller: DialogController,  
           templateUrl: 'editUser.html',
           parent: angular.element(document.body),
           targetEvent: ev,
           clickOutsideToClose: true,
          });
```

**Index.html**:

```
 <md-button class="md-padding" id="popupContainer"  ng-click="vm.addUser($event)" ng-cloak>Add User</md-button>
```

**editUser.html:**

```
<div>
    <md-dialog aria-label="Mango (Fruit)">
        <p>Here I will place my input elements</p>
  </md-dialog>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must pass a path that is relative to the base URL :

```
templateUrl: '/{PATH_TO_THIS_FILE}/editUser.html',
```

Comment: both my index.controller and editUser.html are in same directory i.e. /home

Comment: Can you tell an absolute path to that directory? 
Also can you tell an absolute path to the root directory (usually public or public_html).

If /home is located in the root directory, then try
templateUrl: '/home/editUser.html',

Comment: repo_name/app/home/.....this is where both the index.controller and editUser.html reside....Is this what you are asking?

Comment: tell please: linux/windows? apache/nginx? using php or which server-side language?

Comment: I am using windows, node js and postgressql as my database